When importing products to the Woocommerce structure via API, some attributes are missing
I got an API link from an e-commerce system and pulled these products by writing php code in the functions.php file. The product title, image, description and price come intact. However, the product quality (color, size) and stock number are not available. Since the product attributes are not available, I cannot show the variations. How can I resolve this situation?

You need first to create global attributes with their related terms… Then you will be able to set them in the variable product and generate the related product variations.
